# Sed between blocks of some exact text

Tags: awk, sed

I am struggling on parsing some log file.

Here how it looks like:

```
node_name:  na2-devdb-cssx
run_id:     3c3424f3-8a62-4f4c-b97a-2096a2afc070
start_time: 2015-06-26T21:00:44Z
status:     failure

node_name:  eu1-devsx
run_id:     f5ed13a3-1f02-490f-b518-97de9649daf5
start_time: 2015-06-26T21:00:34Z
status:     success
```

I need to get blocks which have "failure" in its last line of the block.

Ideally would be to consider on time stamp as well. Like if time stamp is like "2015-06-26T2*"

And here what I have tried so far:

```
sed -e '/node_name/./failure/p' /file
```

```
sed -n '/node_name/./failure/p' /file
```

```
awk '/node_name/,/failure/' file
```

```
sed -e 's/node_name\(.*\)failure/\1/' file
```

None of them doesn't work for me. 
It just throws me everything except failure...
For example:

```
[root@localhost chef-repo-zilliant]# sed -n '/node_name/,/failure/p' /tmp/run.txt | head
node_name:  eu1-devdb-linc
run_id:     e49fe64d-567d-4627-a10d-477e17fb6016
start_time: 2015-06-28T20:59:55Z
status:     success

node_name:  eu1-devjs1
run_id:     c6c7f668-b912-4459-9d56-94d1e0788802
start_time: 2015-06-28T20:59:53Z
status:     success
```

Have no idea why it doesn't work. Seems like for all around these methods work fine...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted you tried with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), although you only tagged the question with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), so I will add a solution with it.

You can play with built-in variable that control how to split lines and fields, like:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { RS = ""; FS = OFS = "\n"; ORS = "\n\n" } 
    $NF ~ /failure/ && $(NF-1) ~ /2015-06-26T2/ { print }
' infile
```

`RS = ""` separates records in newlines. `FS` and `OFS` separates fields in lines, and `ORS` is to print output like original input, with a line interleaved.

It yields:

```
node_name:  na2-devdb-cssx
run_id:     3c3424f3-8a62-4f4c-b97a-2096a2afc070
start_time: 2015-06-26T21:00:44Z
status:     failure
```

Comment: This is 100% the right way to do it. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything more interesting you should be using awk.

Answer (score 3):

A way with Gnu sed:

```
sed -n ':a;/^./{H;n;ba;};x;/2015-06-26T21/{/failure$/p;};' file.txt
```

details:

```
:a;           # define the label "a"
/^./ {        # condition: when a line is not empty
    H;        # append it to the buffer space
    n;        # load the next line in the pattern space
    ba;       # go to label "a"
};

x;                 # swap buffer space and pattern space
/2015-06-26T21/ {  # condition: if the needed date is in the block
    /failure$/ p;  # condition: if "failure" is in the block then print
};
```

Comment: Nice, is there a reason you did begin with `.` instead of just `/./`.

Answer (score 1):

Use grep.

```
grep -oPz '\bnode_name:(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*?2015-06-26T2(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*?\bfailure\b' file
```

The main part here is `(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*?` which matches any charactar but not of a blank line, zero or more times.

Comment: Thank you Raj, It works for me but I am not sure the logic on how it works... Can you please explain? What if I would like to narrow down time stamp and make it look for "2015-06-28T20:5*" for example? Thank you once again!

Comment: just change `2015-06-26T2` in my regex to `2015-06-28T20:5`